# Link_to showing wrong confirm message with muliple links having confirm message

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have three link_to links, each with a data-confirm attribute giving a different warning based on the action.  But it only shows the confirm message from the first.

HTML output

```html
<li class="seller__email">
    <a data-confirm="Are you sure you want to resend approval?" href="/admin/sales/2912/send_approval?sale_contract=23159&amp;type=approval">
         Resend Approval
    </a>            
    <a data-confirm="Do you want to send an approval followup email to this seller?" href="/admin/sales/2912/send_approval?sale_contract=23159&amp;type=approval_followup">
         Send Followup (last contact: 4 days ago)
    </a>          
    <a data-confirm="This will rebuild all sale items.  Do you want to continue?" href="/admin/sales/2912/rebuild_remaining_sale_items?sale_contract=23159" id="rebuild_23159">
          Rebuild Sale Items
    </a>  
</li>
```

Rails code

```ruby
  <%= link_to send_approval_admin_sale_path(@sale, sale_contract: sale_contract.id, type: "approval"), data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to resend approval?" } do %>
      Resend Approval
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to send_approval_admin_sale_path(@sale, sale_contract: sale_contract.id, type: "approval_followup"), data: { confirm: "Do you want to send an approval followup email to this seller?" } do %>
      Send Followup (last contact: <%= time_ago_in_words(sale_contract.approval_request_at) + ' ago' %>)
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to rebuild_remaining_sale_items_admin_sale_path(@sale, sale_contract: sale_contract.id), id: "rebuild_#{sale_contract.id}", data: { confirm: "This will rebuild all sale items.  Do you want to continue?" } do %>
      Rebuild Sale Items
  <% end %>
```

When I click on any of the items I get the same confirmation message, "Are you sure you want to resend approval?" (the first confirm message).